# Jquery Form - Storing answers in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, forms

I am making a form/questioner that will ask users a few questions. The first question splits the users into two groups, trucks or cars in this example. Then it asks them a few questions about the vehicle, and at the end, only shows which benefits they said Yes to.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/txwbowzy/3/

So what am I having trouble with? In the JsFiddle, you will see JS for each topic, cars and trucks. I need each topic to have an array that holds the questions, and an array to collect the answers. At the end of the questions, it will read the answers array, and only display which questions they said Yes to. And if you actually test it, you will see it shows the h2 default text, but somehow I need it to show the first key in the array(Car question 1 instead of "hidden").

```
$('#q1').show();

var qq = 0;

$('#q1 input:radio').change(function () {
var ans = $('input[name="genius"]:checked').val();

$('.q-block').fadeOut(500);
if (ans == 'q1-y'){
    $('#ecQuestions').fadeIn(500);
}
if (ans == 'q1-n'){
    $('#lgQuestions').fadeIn(500);
}
});
//car
$('#lgQuestions input:radio').change(function () {

var ansLg = $('#lgQuestions input[name="genius"]:checked').val();
var lgQuestions = ["Car Question 1", "Car Question 2", "Car Question 3"];
var lgAnswers = new Array(5);
var activeLg = document.getElementById('activeLg');

if (qq<lgQuestions.length) {
    activeLg.innerHTML = lgQuestions[qq];
    qq++;
    $('#lgQuestions input:radio').prop( "checked", false );
}
else {
    $('.q-block').fadeOut(500);
    $('#solution').fadeIn(500);
    document.getElementById('benefit').innerHTML = "Car benefits";
}

});
//truck
$('#ecQuestions input:radio').change(function () {

var ansEc = $('#ecQuestions input[name="genius"]:checked').val();
var ecQuestions = ["Truck Question 1", "Truck Question 2", "Truck Question 3"];
var ecAnswers = new Array(5);
var activeEc = document.getElementById('activeEc');

if (qq<ecQuestions.length) {
    activeEc.innerHTML = ecQuestions[qq];
    qq++;
    $('#ecQuestions input:radio').prop( "checked", false );
}
else {
    $('.q-block').fadeOut(500);
    $('#solution').fadeIn(500);
    document.getElementById('benefit').innerHTML = "Truck benefits";
}   

});

$('#q-contain input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');

$('#q-contain label').click(function () {
$(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, I hope that I'm understanding your question. The problem is that the functions you have on your lgQuestions and ecQuestions radio buttons' change events need to be called inside the function on your q1 change event. I believe that this modified fiddle has the behavior your going for.

UPDATE: To show the questions that were answered 'yes', you can add them to your display list as you go. Give the ul element an id and leave the items empty (you can see this in the fiddle). Then create a new li item for each yes answer and append it to the ul element. The updated code is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/skizer/uuy06yf7/

```
$('#q1').show();

var qq = 0;

$('#q1 input:radio').change(function () {
    var ans = $('input[name="genius"]:checked').val();

    $('.q-block').fadeOut(500);
    if (ans == 'q1-y'){
        $('#ecQuestions').fadeIn(500);
        truckQuestionChange();
    }
    if (ans == 'q1-n'){
        $('#lgQuestions').fadeIn(500);
        carQuestionChange();
    }
});
//car

function carQuestionChange() {
    var ansLg = $('#lgQuestions input[name="genius"]:checked').val(),
        lgQuestions = ["Car Question 1", "Car Question 2", "Car Question 3"],    
        activeLg = document.getElementById('activeLg'),
        liElement;

    if(ansLg && ansLg === "lg-y")
    {
        liElement = document.createElement("li");
        liElement.innerHTML = lgQuestions[qq - 1];
        $("#benefitsList").append(liElement);      
    }

    if (qq<lgQuestions.length) {       
        activeLg.innerHTML = lgQuestions[qq];
        qq++;
        $('#lgQuestions input:radio').prop( "checked", false );
    }
    else {
        $('.q-block').fadeOut(500);
        $('#solution').fadeIn(500);
        document.getElementById('benefit').innerHTML = "Car benefits";
    }
}

function truckQuestionChange() {
    var ansEc = $('#ecQuestions input[name="genius"]:checked').val(),
        ecQuestions = ["Truck Question 1", "Truck Question 2", "Truck Question 3"],
        activeEc = document.getElementById('activeEc');

    if(ansEc && ansEc === "ec-y")
    {
        liElement = document.createElement("li");
        liElement.innerHTML = ecQuestions[qq - 1];
        $("#benefitsList").append(liElement);
    }

    if (qq<ecQuestions.length) {
        activeEc.innerHTML = ecQuestions[qq];
        qq++;
        $('#ecQuestions input:radio').prop( "checked", false );
    }
    else {
        $('.q-block').fadeOut(500);
        $('#solution').fadeIn(500);
        document.getElementById('benefit').innerHTML = "Truck benefits";
    }   
}

$('#lgQuestions input:radio').change(carQuestionChange);
//truck
$('#ecQuestions input:radio').change(truckQuestionChange);

$('#q-contain input:radio').addClass('input_hidden');

$('#q-contain label').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');    
});
```

If you need to store the answer in an array, its scope needs to be outside of the change function. You created your answers array inside the change function which means it is getting overwritten every time the user clicks an answer. Instead, I would declare an empty array where you declare your 'qq' variable:

```
var qq = 0,
    lgAnswers = [];
```

Then push the answer into the array:

```
if (qq<lgQuestions.length) {       
    lgAnswers.push(lgQuestions[qq]);
}
```

The answers will be stored in an array that has the full document scope.

Comment: Awesome, that makes a lot more sense than the way I had it. But the main issue I'm having is storing the answers in an array, and only displaying the Yes answers in the benefits page.